# Download files by script or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

In a web site, not mine, there a result to a search

```
<a href="show?file=191719&token=r1j">
<a href="show?file=191720&token=gh5">
<a href="show?file=191721&token=98j">
.....
<a href="show?file=191733&token=ty0">
```

and after I click on one of them I go to a page i fill a form and after I go to download page and i click on the link:

```
<a href="download?file=191719&token=r1j">
```

And i have to do that manually for 150 file wich is too long !!

what i want is by using a script or something, i download all the files directly by getting the file id in result page and put it in download link.

Comment: What is the page? I'll prepare an example for you

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH.  you have to start the search from this link because it's a post link https://www.marches-publics.gouv.fr/?page=entreprise.EntrepriseAdvancedSearch&searchAnnCons

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? Please provide more details, I don't know where are those <a href ... </a> with tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this javascript snippet, where `http://www.that-website.com/` is the url of that website, AND DO NOT download all files all at once if there are too many, download couple dozens each time by specifying start and finish file number, *Note that the browser popup blocker will block this so you need to allow popup from this webpage in your popup blocker in your browser*

**JS:**

```
var fileNumber,
start = 191719,
finish = 191729;
for(fileNumber = start; fileNumber <= finish; ++fileNumber){
    window.open("http://www.that-website.com/download?file=" + fileNumber);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Since random token are implemented in the url the easiest way is to enter it manually in multi-lines of `window.open()`, something like this:

```
window.open("http://www.that-website.com/download?file=191719&token=r1j");
window.open("http://www.that-website.com/download?file=191720&token=gh5");
window.open("http://www.that-website.com/download?file=191721&token=98j");
```

and so on for couple dozens.

**UPDATE 2:**
See an example of this in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4g9o3xrL/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- COPY BUNCH OF THE URLs AND PASTE THEM IN HERE THEN RELOAD THE PAGE, THEN REPEAT OVER AND OVER UNTIL IT IS ALL DONE! -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('a').each(function(){
                    var showLink = $(this).attr('href');
                    var downloadLink = showLink.replace("show?file", "download?file");
                    window.open("http://www.example.com/" + downloadLink);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With the above code, this an HTML page ON YOUR COMPUTER, copy several original from that website page links - *like: `<a href="http://www.example.com/show?file=111&token=23f">TEST</a>`* to your local page and run it, still it is highly recommended that you paste 10-30 links each time.

Comment: yes that's good but i forget to say that there is a other parameter in query look at my edited question.. and if the ids are not sorted so i want first get the ids and the other param with a script and after that downled them.

Comment: since token usually randon, and they are in this case too you cannot use for loop, instead type 10 lines of `window.open()` each one with its file number and the special random token, i'll update the answer to show an example

Comment: yes but there is not a way to search for ids and token in html code ? because do it for 150 manually i win nothing by your solution.

Comment: You win escaping the form filling for 150 times :), however you can save the page, and grab the values of file and token for each link, but it differs depending on the DOM structure of the webpage, and it might need some tweeking to add a class name for example to pick them all up with jquery, so save the page and show us the HTML lines for these links in that page

Comment: i show it in my question there is lines of `<a>` links in the html code.

Comment: You showed an example, each links might be in any DOM elements, `p`, `div`, `li` etc, and mostly there are others `<a>` tags in that page, the answer is UPDATED though to fulfill the OP

Comment: yes that's good we suppose that `<a>` elements have `foo` class but now the problem is that the web site is not mine how can i run your js code on a web site ?

Comment: i edit your answer to fit with my problem... just can you explain me why it is highly recommended that i download 10-30 links each time ?

Answer (score 1):

You can generate links using excel, save it as txt file and download using wget with -i parameter.

Comment: how to generate links using excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **[*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)** to download files in parallel as blobs and then use `<a download>`s to initiate download behaviour. This will have same-origin-policy restrictions though.

General idea is

```
// fetch
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var uri = URL.createObjectURL(this.response); // generate URI to access Blob
    // write, see below
});
xhr.open('GET', target_file_href);
xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // state we want the target as a blob/file
xhr.send(); // send the request
// ---------------

// write
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = uri;
a.setAttribute('download'); // make this a download link rather than a change page
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
// cleanup a, uri
```

Here is a parallel file downloader I wrote in ES5 which limits the number of concurrent downloads.

```
function ParallelDownloader(max_parallel, retry_on_error) {
    this.links = [];
    this.current = 0;
    this.max_parallel = max_parallel || 5;
    this.retry_on_error = !!retry_on_error;
}
ParallelDownloader.prototype = Object.create(null);
ParallelDownloader.prototype.add = function (url) {
    if ('splice' in url && 'length' in url)
        this.links.push.apply(this.links, url);
    else
        this.links.push(url);
    this.downloadNext();
};
ParallelDownloader.prototype.downloadNext = (function () {
    function load() {
        var a = document.createElement('a'),
            uri = URL.createObjectURL(this.response),
            cd = this.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition'),
            filename = null;
        if (cd) {
            cd = cd.match(/;\s+filename=(.+)/);
            if (cd) filename = cd[1];
        }
        if (null === filename) {
            cd = this.__url.match(/\/([^/]+?(?=\?|$))/);
            if (cd) filename = cd[1];
        }
        if (null !== filename) a.setAttribute('download', filename);
        else a.setAttribute('download');
        a.setAttribute('href', uri);
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(uri);
        --this.__parallelDownloader.current;
        this.__parallelDownloader.downloadNext();
    }
    function error() {
        --this.__parallelDownloader.current;
        if (this.__parallelDownloader.retry_on_error) {
            console.warn('Will retry', this.__url);
            this.__parallelDownloader.unshift(this.__url);
        }
        this.__parallelDownloader.downloadNext();
    }
    return function () {
        var url;
        ++this.current;
        if (this.current > this.max_parallel || this.links.length === 0) {
            --this.current;
            return;
        }
        url = this.links.shift();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.__parallelDownloader = this;
        xhr.__url = url;
        xhr.addEventListener('load', load);
        xhr.addEventListener('error', error);
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send();
        this.downloadNext();
    };
}());
```

To use it you would do, e.g.

```
var pd = new ParallelDownloader(10); // max 10 concurrent downloads
pd.add([
    '/path1.txt', '/path2.pub', '/path3.pdf'
]);
// or
pd.add('/path4.txt');
pd.add('/path5.txt');
// etc
```

Download attempt initiates as soon as a link is added and there is a slot free. *(If you enable `retry_on_error` I haven't limited it so you may get infinite loops)*

Comment: thanks man but i have a `post` url not a `get` and i have first get the html code so with `post` it's impossible. unfortunately.